# align blog post in body to the left

Tags: html, blogger

I am using a third party template. For my blog post, the display is okay on desktop. But on mobile version (tablet and phone), the post body is right align. I want it to shift to the left.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {
.picsizer {
width: 100%;
}
.fullwrap {
  position: relative;
}
.post-outer {
width: 100%;
}
#stickyme {
    width: 100%;
}
.labelblog .post-outer {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
}

    ~~~~<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-z541xJZy8o4/XT0QfBsglbI/AAAAAAAABKU/LcYLqVn4A1MMDRODOxLeewRDDasnVCq0gCKgBGAs/s1600/famous.png" imageanchor="1" ><img border="0" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-z541xJZy8o4/XT0QfBsglbI/AAAAAAAABKU/LcYLqVn4A1MMDRODOxLeewRDDasnVCq0gCKgBGAs/s320/famous.png" width="320" height="320" data-original-width="636" data-original-height="636" /></a></div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/canvas-chess/source/pgn.min.css">
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/canvas-chess/source/canvaschess-0.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/canvas-chess/source/pgnviewer-0.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var viewer = new CHESS.PgnViewer({
        pgn_uri: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/canvas-chess/pgn/lasker_capablanca_1921.pgn',
        piece_set: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/canvas-chess/pieces/merida'
    });
</script>

....
I added in the html code. Here's the link to the full blog post. It was done a while back and I am doing a fixing of the website.

https://abigaildemo.blogspot.com/2018/10/four-move-checkmates.html
```

Comment: Please post your relevant code, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: We need the html too.

Comment: @takendarkk - I added the post to put in the html.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer this.

You can try to add:

```
text-align: left;
```

on

```
.post-outher
```

Like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {
    .picsizer {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .fullwrap {
        position: relative;
    }
    .post-outer {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
    }
    #stickyme {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .labelblog .post-outer {
        padding-left: 40px;
        padding-right: 40px;        
    }
}
```

Or like this because of you can't provide an example on how do you implement your CSS code into HTML code.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {
    .picsizer {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .fullwrap {
         position: relative;
    }
    .post-outer {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #stickyme {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .labelblog .post-outer {
        padding-left: 40px;
        padding-right: 40px;
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: I try your solution but I didn't work at all. On mobile phone the post is cut off.

Comment: You can try this hack: by adding `padding-left:-15px` into class `.canvaschesspgn` or copy paste this code  `.canvaschesspgn {padding-left:-15px;}` before `</style>` on your blogger template.

Comment: It's seem work on my side, chack up on https://ibb.co/GnWp7XL. But, if you don't accept it, it's okay.